# Android ImageView XML no leak vs BitmapFactory.decodeResource leak ?

Tags: android, xml, memory-leaks, bitmap, bitmapfactory

Getting OOM big time in my game UI (I'm only targeting kitkat and above)

I noticed that if I use a android:src="@drawable/empty_screen_game_setup" in XML, leaving and entering the activity always has the same memory usage.

If I DON'T set src in XML, but rather use the following google code, leaving and entering the activity makes the memory usage climb like crazy. This is a test app with no other code because I'm trying to understand the OOM. So much conflicting info out there!!

Is it better to just use src in XML memory-wise? I was hoping to use one set of ressources in no-dpi and scale them to size with bitmapfactory given the screen size but I guess that's not best :(

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

And in onCreate:

```
glass = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewGlass);
glass.setImageBitmap( decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.empty_screen_game_setup, 500, 300) );
```

Comment: No need to do that .Put them in no-dpi and system will scale for you.But it's better to put drawable 2x in xhdpi and 3x in xxhdpi.

Comment: could you post the entire Activity so we can see where the leak might be occurring?

Comment: That was the entire activity, nothing else since this was a test just to see what happens when using this code. 

I did just switch to using Picasso or Glide, solved all these weird issues and real simple to use :)